# Android Studio Bluetooth application

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth

I am making a small application, in which the phone connects automatically using Bluetooth protocol to a certain device, so basically I am trying to do this:

- I have a list with the discovered devices.
- When the user taps on any element (device) from list, the phone should connect to a device that is "hard coded".

This is the event generated when the user taps on the list:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        //first cancel discovery because its very memory intensive.
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on a device.");
        String deviceName = mBTDevices.get(i).getName();
        String deviceAddress = mBTDevices.get(i).getAddress();

        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceName = " + deviceName);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: deviceAddress = " + deviceAddress); 

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to pair with " + deviceName);
            for (BluetoothDevice device: mBTDevices){
                if (device.equals("HTC")){
                    device.createBond();
                }
            }

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    Button btnEnableDisable_Discoverable;

    public ArrayList mBTDevices = new ArrayList();

    public DeviceListAdapter mDeviceListAdapter;

    ListView lvNewDevices;
```

My question is, where am I mistaking?

```
for (BluetoothDevice device: mBTDevices){
    if (device.equals("HTC")){
        device.createBond();
```

Because the application does not behave as expected. More precisely when I tap on a device from the list I would like to automatically create a bond with the device that has the name "HTC", instead nothing happens.

Comment: Check it https://github.com/berateyuboglu/Bluetooth21

Comment: Your code is weird. Why do you have a method out of a class, and the class below? Please organize it properly with an [edit]. You will notice how I added the bold formatting (a neat trick: use `<pre><code>` tags instead of spaces to add code formatting, then use `<b>` tags to bold stuff).

Comment: Yes you are right , I copy pasted the method first and then the class, I will keep in mind you advice in the future thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `device.getName().equals("HTC")` instead of `device.equals("HTC")`.

At the moment your code is comparing an object of type BluetoothDevice to a string. Therefore, even if the device is available, you will not get a match, so the line `device.createBond();` will never be reached.